Image CID not displaying correctly in HTML email with Mailjet
Hello Stack Overflow community,
I'm encountering an issue with embedding an image using CID (Content-ID) in an HTML email sent through Mailjet. Despite following the correct setup, the image does not display and instead, the alt text is shown.
Here is the simplified version of my code (with sensitive information removed):
using Mailjet.Client.Resources;
using Mailjet.Client.TransactionalEmails;
using Mailjet.Client;

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestSendEmailWithEmbeddedImage
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static string API_KEY = @"API_KEY_REDACTED";
        static string SecretKey = @"SECRET_KEY_REDACTED";

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var senderEmail = "SENDER_EMAIL_REDACTED";
            var destEmail = "DEST_EMAIL_REDACTED";
            var senderName = "support";
        
            MailjetClient _client = new MailjetClient(API_KEY, SecretKey);
            var imageBase64 = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAIAAAACUFjqAAAAEklEQVR4nGP8z4APMOGVHbHSAEEsAROxCnMTAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
            var contentId = "ABCD"; // Unique identifier for the image

            var imageName = "image.png"; // Name of the image
            var body = $@"
                    <html>
                    <body>
                        <p>Voici une image :</p>
                        <img src=""cid:{contentId}"" alt=""image""/>
                    </body>
                    </html>";

            var attach = new Attachment(imageName, "image/png", imageBase64, contentId);
       
            var email = new TransactionalEmailBuilder()
                .WithFrom(new SendContact(senderEmail, senderName))
                .WithSubject("titre")
                .WithHtmlPart(body)
                .WithTo(new SendContact(destEmail))
                .WithAttachment(attach)
                .Build();

            var response = await _client.SendTransactionalEmailAsync(email);

            bool good = (response.Messages.First().Errors == null);
        }
    }
}

The email is sent successfully, but the image does not display. Here is the raw source of the received email:
From - Fri Jul 12 23:39:43 2024
X-Account-Key: account1
X-UIDL: 4A3663448AAF4AD4AB442D639AB2CEA5
X-Mozilla-Status: 0001
X-Mozilla-Status2: 10000000
X-Mozilla-Keys:                                                                                 
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.5 (2021-03-20) on winheb04
X-Spam-Flag: YES
X-Spam-Level: ****
X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=4.7 required=0.0 tests=FORGED_GMAIL_RCVD,
    FREEMAIL_FROM,HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_08,HTML_MESSAGE,MIME_HTML_ONLY,
    SPOOFED_FREEMAIL,SPOOFED_FREEMAIL_NO_RDNS,SPOOF_GMAIL_MID autolearn=no
    autolearn_force=no version=3.4.5
X-Spam-Report: 
    *  0.0 FREEMAIL_FROM Sender email is commonly abused enduser mail
    *      provider
    *      [HIDDEN]
    *  1.0 FORGED_GMAIL_RCVD 'From' gmail.com does not match 'Received'
    *      headers
    *  0.1 MIME_HTML_ONLY BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
    *  0.6 HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_08 BODY: HTML: images with 400-800 bytes of
    *      words
    *  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
    *  1.5 SPOOFED_FREEMAIL_NO_RDNS From SPOOFED_FREEMAIL and no rDNS
    *  0.0 SPOOFED_FREEMAIL No description available.
    *  1.5 SPOOF_GMAIL_MID From Gmail but it doesn't seem to be...
Received: from o22.p25.mailjet.com ([185.189.236.22]) by winheb04.ikoula.com with
 MailEnable ESMTPS (version=TLS1_2 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384); Fri, 12 Jul 2024 23:39:37 +0200
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; q=dns/txt;
  d=bnc3.mailjet.com; i=HIDDEN@a2512324.bnc3.mailjet.com; s=mailjet2; x=1720827576;
  h=message-id:from:from:to:to:subject:subject:date:date:list-unsubscribe-post:list-unsubscribe:
  feedback-id:x-csa-complaints:x-mj-mid:x-report-abuse-to:mime-version:
  content-type;
  bh=zXJK7SKHFOl/sZ0wgwFut4B+r9oba3LnSSekwPp+BCE=;
  b=dCkZ5v6dF5hwVAB4faDY2OpiAKTP/lHlm4pNJCLk1gc8urQXD6McZTHmr
 NPFmcvPRpg2visYRYmUN82ZBmE1MGa6loHZwiE/QjU2cLHDnQY/88o2VYgHh
 xzMwqiEmI/aw6eDd4VE0zXE3LCwqgjFNcaPckUFnSQIZSOW/Hwx2vU=
Return-Path:
    <8611192a.BAAABcYgl5sAAAAAAAAAADrzFk8AAAACCP4AAAAAACZVxABmkaKY@a2512324.bnc3.mailjet.com>
Message-Id: <8611192a.BAAABcYgl5sAAAAAAAAAADrzFk8AAAACCP4AAAAAACZVxABmkaKY@mailjet.com>
From: support <contactyadusurf@gmail.com>
To: mathieu.jacquinot@yadusurf.com
Subject: [4.7] titre
Date: Fri, 12 Jul 2024 21:39:36 +0000
List-Unsubscribe-Post: List-Unsubscribe=One-Click
List-Unsubscribe:
    <mailto:unsub-8611192a.ssxz1.vps6h30uv5ll@bnc3.mailjet.com>,
    <https://ssxz1.mjt.lu/unsub2?m=BAAABcYgl5sAAAAAAAAAADrzFk8AAAACCP4AAAAAACZVxABmkaKYykdiv6e9T1akWSrodGCj0QAjtK0&b=8611192a&e=a0ab8a57&x=G5WbUbsRpVkLljxWbgJSl6SzhpLmsUcB66oyX8WN774>
Feedback-Id: 42.2512324.2340013:MJ
X-CSA-Complaints: csa-complaints@eco.de
X-MJ-Mid:
    BAAABcYgl5sAAAAAAAAAADrzFk8AAAACCP4AAAAAACZVxABmkaKYykdiv6e9T1akWSrodGCj0QAjtK0
X-REPORT-ABUSE-TO: Message sent by Mailjet please report to
    abuse@mailjet.com with a copy of the message
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="=-+zpCN5rjhXag2yK+qwRs"
Return-Path: <8611192a.BAAABcYgl5sAAAAAAAAAADrzFk8AAAACCP4AAAAAACZVxABmkaKY@a2512324.bnc3.mailjet.com>
X-Spam-Prev-Subject: titre

--=-+zpCN5rjhXag2yK+qwRs
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
<body>
    <p>Voici une image :</p>
    <img src="cid:ABCD" alt="image"/>
</body>
</html>

--=-+zpCN5rjhXag2yK+qwRs
Content-Type: image/png; charset=utf-8; name=image.png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=image.png
Content-Id: <ABCD>

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAIAAAACUFjqAAAAEklEQVR4nGP8z4APMOGVHbHSAEEs
AROxCnMTAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC

--=-+zpCN5rjhXag2yK+qwRs--

Here is a screenshot showing the result where the image does not display, and the alt text is shown instead:

Note that the image, a red square, is visible only as an attachement file (image.png)
I've checked the CID format, ensured it matches in the HTML and the attachment, but the image still doesn't display. I suspect there might be something I'm missing or a specific issue with how Mailjet handles embedded images.
I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!
